# Create new columns based on a condition

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe in python that looks like:

| id | Date | wages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2018-01-01 | 100 |
| A | 2018-02-01 | 200 |
| A | 2018-03-01 | 100 |
| B | 2018-01-01 | 200 |
| B | 2018-02-01 | 100 |
| B | 2018-03-01 | 200 |

How can I transform this in a new dataframe that looks like the one below:

| id | 2018-01-01 | 2018-02-01 | 2018-03-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 200 | 100 |
| B | 200 | 100 | 200 |

Comment: use [df.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Yes, pivot_table solved it!!!!